# gud-gdb emacs 24 not working

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs24

I'm having difficulties with gdb under emacs 24.
I compiled my c code with the -g switch, and the symbol table loads in gdb.
The problem I'm having is that no source code is shown when I load my application, no breakpoints are visible. I guess there appears to be no connection between the source code buffer and gdb buffer.

I have used gdb under emacs before (emacs 22, and 23) and it worked well and now it doesn't.
I also tried it under `emacs -q` so no plugins are loaded in case my .emacs was at fault, no joy.

Just to recap (so I don't get "compile with -g" answers):

- I compiled with -g I loaded emacs with no plugins
- I used `annotate=3`with gud-gdb
- I even tried gdb-mi (doesn't work at all, didn't pursue
  this road any further)

Gdb ain't working with source code showing (with breakpoints). 
What can I do to fix it, or at least how can I find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 9):

`M-x gud-gdb` is not for use with annotate=3 but with --fullname (aka --annotate=1, IIRC).

Comment: Using --fullname (which the man page says should be -fullname, ugh) works for me (yay! thank you!), but --annotate=2 doesn't. So I don't think they're the same.

Comment: That's right: IIRC, `--fullname` is equivalent to `--annotate=1` and not `--annotate=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `M-x gdb` with `-i=mi` instead of `--annotate=3`.

Then it worked for me, but it's damn slow in my case :/

Answer (score 0):

When did you build Emacs 24?  There's been a lot of churn in the gdb/gud area from emacs-devel.  If you repro problems in the latest (i.e. today's) build, report bugs ASAP.  The pretest is coming to an end very soon.

Comment: It's version 24.0.94 march 5th. Also I'm not sure what the bug is, I think reporting "Stuff ain't working" isn't gonna cut it ;-)

Comment: switching back to stable build 23, don't have the time to test nightlies at the moment. I figured, if it works it works if it doesn't, meh.