# Emacs gdb not running

Tags: emacs, gdb

I enter gdb within emacs using `M-x gdb`. Then, when I execute `b main`, I get the following output:

```
b main                                                                             
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000d61: file hanoi.c, line 27.                                
                        (gdb)                                                        
MI_HOOK_RESULT={HOOK_TYPE="breakpoint_create",bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",d\
  isp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000000100000d61",func="main",file="hanoi.c",line="\
  27",shlib="/Users/rdp/Desktop/Hanoi-Moves_testcases/play",times="0"}},time={wallcl\
  ock="0.00104",user="0.00049",system="0.00027",start="1347691065.681152",end="13476\
  91065.682197"}
```

When I try to run the program, I get this output:

```
r                                                                    |21  } 14Starting program: /Users/rdp/Desktop/Hanoi-Moves_testcases/play                   
                                            (gdb)                                    |24} 16time={wallclock="0.00009",user="0.00005",system="0.00004",start="1347691082.360725\|25 ",end="1347691082.360816"}                                                       (gdb)  n

The program is not being run.
```

Why do I get a verbose output, and why can't I step through the code?

Comment: After posting my answer (see below), I realized that `gud-gdb` works fairly well for me, while `gdb` breaks. Which one did you use?

Comment: gud-gdb is better, for now, but still broken in subtle ways. But that's not the issue. The issue is emacs gdb is broken. My worries are approximately 3-fold ...  I worry that (1) emacs users will just let this slide (2) rather than it getting fixed, some standard will be cited that claims it's not broken (3) soon gud-gdb will be unequivocally broken as well (I'll cop to paranoia on #3, but it's *educated* paranoia).

Comment: Sorry, I feel strongly about this. I have tried ... and given up on ... several suggested forum patches with defuns/progns about dedicated windows (of course I appreciate peoples' efforts). I have been using Emacs for over two decades, and I have come to expect that Emacs' "do it yourself"-ness is *ONLY* for customization. Basic functionality (such as gdb) should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs 24 seems to have broken GUD (the interface to gdb and other debuggers). There was some brawl about it on the IRC channel, and one person was actually claiming it to work for him, but I'm also getting very weird behavior. Googling also reveals the following (and some more): [gud-gdb emacs 24 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676135/gud-gdb-emacs-24-not-working)

I would try to make a minimal test-case of it failing and file a bug report.

Edit: You might want to try `gud-gdb` in place of `gdb`. I don't know what differences there are but it seems to work for me. (Didn't test comprehensively.)

Comment: Running emacs 24.2.1 in OSX.  Can confirm that gdb behaves the way the OP described, and that gud-gdb works fine.

Comment: i've had to switch to gud-gdb as well as gdb is totally broken in emacs 24 - but gud-gdb doesn't have the nice red circle icons on breakpoints which is a real shame

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I am running 10.7 and emacs 24.3.  The version of gdb that ships with xcode 4 (the latest for this platform) is too old to work with gdb mode.  If you get the latest one from source and build it, using macports to obtain its dependencies, (the macports build of gdb was not working for me at the time), gdb mode works, including gdb-many-windows, which I highly recommend.

Edit: also, gud-gdb is apparently an old mode, so it may work, but you "really" want gdb mode and gdb-many-windows......