# Cannot access Memory at address function parameter passing issue

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, shared-libraries

In my `main()` function I have a local variable:

```
datastruct pdw_frame;
```

I fill it with data and pass it to two functions that are on adjacent lines in `main()`, e.g.

```
datastruct_to_pdw(&pdw_frame, 0, &pdw); /* ok */
hash_streams = get_streams(&pdw_frame, &result_frame); /* not ok */
```

whilst stepping into `datastruct_to_pdw()` with `gdb` I can look at the 1st function parameter no problem, e.g.

```
(gdb) p *pdw_frame
```

returns a description of the struct

however, when stepping into the 2nd function and trying to do the same, I get:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0xcccccccd
```

I cannot understand why I can dereference the pointer from the 1st function parameter but not the 2nd

The functions in point are contained in a shared library that I call from main(). The functions are defined in different files and their prototypes are in different header files. I have checked my `Makefile` to ensure they are all getting built. Inspection of the shared lib confirms that both functions are present, e.g.

```
nm mylib.so

000251a1 T datastruct_to_pdw
00027348 T get_streams
```

How can one function call work and not the other?

Function prototypes are:

```
void datastruct_to_pdw(const datastruct *const pulse_data, size_t i, Pdw *pdw);
stream_t* get_streams(datastruct *pdw_frame, resultstruct *result_frame);
```

The debug version of my shared library has the following compiler flags set:

```
DEBUG_CFLAGS := -fPIC -g -Wall -DDEBUG=1
```

with these settings I get no warnings when building from the Makefile

Stepping through the code, checking the value of pdw_frame as I go gives:

In main() prior to call to datastruct_to_pdw():

```
(gdb) p pdw_frame
$2 = {ptoa = 0x8051e98, prf = 0x804e008, ppw = 0x804ff50, pamp = 0x8053de0, pbr = 0x8055d28, n = 1000, truth = 0x8057c70}

(gdb) p &pdw_frame
$5 = (datastruct *) 0xbfffe9e0
```

stepping into datastruct_to_pdw():

```
(gdb) p pulse_data
$4 = (const datastruct * const) 0xbfffe9e0

(gdb) p *pulse_data
$3 = {ptoa = 0x8051e98, prf = 0x804e008, ppw = 0x804ff50, pamp = 0x8053de0, pbr = 0x8055d28, n = 1000, truth = 0x8057c70}
```

return from datastruct_to_pdw() back in main():

```
(gdb) p pdw_frame
$9 = {ptoa = 0x8051e98, prf = 0x804e008, ppw = 0x804ff50, pamp = 0x8053de0, pbr = 0x8055d28, n = 1000, truth = 0x8057c70}

(gdb) p &pdw_frame
$8 = (datastruct *) 0xbfffe9e0
```

stepping into get_streams():

```
(gdb) p pdw_frame
$10 = (datastruct *) 0x40c24f80 (why is this different to &pdw_frame in main()?)

(gdb) p *pdw_frame
Cannot access memory at address 0x40c24f80 (why??)
```

return from get_streams() back in main():

```
(gdb) p pdw_frame
$13 = {ptoa = 0x8051e98, prf = 0x804e008, ppw = 0x804ff50, pamp = 0x8053de0, pbr = 0x8055d28, n = 1000, truth = 0x8057c70}

(gdb) p &pdw_frame
$14 = (datastruct *) 0xbfffe9e0
```

Note I thought perhaps the fact that I was using the same name for both the local variable, `pdw_frame` (of type `datastruct`), in `main()` and parameter name in the `get_streams()` function (of type `datastruct*`) may be causing a problem so I tried renaming the 1st parameter of `get_streams()` to something completely different but this made no difference to the error

running the program through valgrind doesn't seem to suggest any problems (I think), e.g.:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes <my_program>

==12371== 
==12371== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12371==     in use at exit: 1,880 bytes in 1 blocks
==12371==   total heap usage: 35,810 allocs, 35,809 frees, 102,124,128 bytes allocated
==12371== 
==12371== 1,880 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==12371==    at 0x402A2FB: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==12371==    by 0x41D048B: monstartup (gmon.c:134)
==12371==    by 0x8049F60: __gmon_start__ (in /home/ben/projects/glamdring/RESTRICTED/core_harness/build/linux/release/GlamdringHarness_rel)
==12371==    by 0x40D45A9: ??? (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so)
==12371== 
==12371== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12371==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12371==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12371==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12371==    still reachable: 1,880 bytes in 1 blocks
==12371==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12371== 
==12371== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12371== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Profiling timer expired
```

I should also add that when i run my unit-test suite which compiles and links to a single executable rather than accessing the functions through a shared library I don't have any problems of this kind.

Just added a new function:

```
void dummy_utility(int n)
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return;
}
```

called it from `main()` like this:

```
dummy_utility(42);
```

stepped into it using `gdb` and got:

```
(gdb) p n
$4 = 1086476160
```

it must be picking up an old lib but when i search for the shared lib, e.g.

`$ locate libProgram_dbg.so` (_dbg version has debugging symbols and no optimisation)

I get a single file in my `build/linux/debug` dir which is as i would expect, when I look at the timestamp of the shared lib there it shows it has just been rebuilt! I am really confused..

Here is the output from running info registers in gdb:

just before call to `dummy_utility()`:

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xc  12
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0xbfffe454   -1073748908
ebx            0x11 17
esp            0xbfffe8c0   0xbfffe8c0
ebp            0xbfffec78   0xbfffec78
esi            0x8053dd0    134561232
edi            0x1f38   7992
eip            0x8049d82    0x8049d82 <main+3884>
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

on stepping into `dummy_utility()`:

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xbfffea98   -1073747304
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x2a 42
ebx            0xb7fd9000   -1208119296
esp            0xbfffe8b8   0xbfffe8b8
ebp            0xbfffe8d0   0xbfffe8d0
esi            0x8053dd0    134561232
edi            0x1f38   7992
eip            0xb7fc22cc   0xb7fc22cc <dummy_utility+18>
eflags         0x296    [ PF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

stepping through `dummy_utility()` in an attempt to return from `main()`, `gdb` tells me:

```
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

running `ldd ProgramHarness_dbg` gives:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76e7000)
libGlamdring_dbg.so => /home/ben/projects/core/build/linux/debug/libProgram_dbg.so (0xb76a4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7646000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb763c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7489000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76e8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb746e000)
```

The location of the shared lib is as expected..

Comment: Too little information, but: enable as many warnings as you can, and make sure there's nothing serious that the compiler is flagging. Make sure all code is re-built.

Comment: post prototype for `get_streams`

Comment: added some more info as requested..

Comment: What do you get for `p &pdw_frame` before and after calling `datastruct_to_pdw()`.

Comment: inspection of pdw_frame via gdb added..

Comment: Are you on x86-64? If so print  RDI, RSI, RDX when you enter get_streams

Comment: 1. Verify that your main() sees a proper prototype for both your functions (i.e. compile with warnings enabled & fix all warnings. all.). 2. Comment out the first function call, to be sure that function doesn't trash your memory. 3. Run your program through valgrind. 4. Verify that a new version of your shared lib is being used, not an old one. (Same with header files)..

Comment: @skwllsp not sure how you do that?

Comment: @nos already running -Wall with no warnings on build, what others would you suggest? -pedantic maybe?

Comment: It really shouldn't make a difference, but have you tried changing the formal parameters of `get_streams()` to take `*pdw_frame` as a const?  (This may involve changing the innards to a dummy function.)

Comment: my gut feeling is that it has to be some sort of linking issue but i can't see anything that looks wrong in the code or Makefiles - I've done several make clean/make iterations but its still exhibiting the same error

Comment: You could test whether it's a linking issue by pasting all the function definitions into the same file...

Comment: e.g like my unit-test which i know work

Comment: Are you sure the right binary for the lib is used and not an old stale version lying around in some path found first when parsing `LD_LOAD_LIBRARY` for doing these run-time tests?

Comment: @Hiett - step in function and run `info registers`

Comment: @alk what you are saying sounds like it must be the solution, e.g. old functions are working - new ones aren't. But I can only find a single instance of the shared lib and its timestamp is correct, i.e a few minutes old (see update to OP)

Comment: Using `locate` not necessarily finds all files, as the locate-db might not be up-to-date. Use `find / -name libProgram_dbg.so`

Comment: My latest move was to make a static version, i.e. squashing my main() and the functions from the shared lib into a single binary (linking a .a rather than .so file with -static). This seems to work - reinforcing the fact that something is going awry with calling the shared lib from main()

Comment: @alk running find I can confirm there is only the one expected instance of the shared lib. Is it possible that I have corrupted it in some way? I can still see all the functions in there using `nm` though

Comment: What does `ldd <program>` tells you about the dependencies of the program used for the tests.

Comment: @alk have added ldd output to the OP

Comment: How is `get_streams` declared? Do you by any chance have another local `pdw_frame` inside `get_streams` that is not a parameter?

Comment: right, new day, fresh brain and i find this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435183/emacs-gdb-not-running Run gdb-gud rather than gdb and everything works. Thanks emacs24 ;-) Thats a day and a half I could have had my feet up supping on a large brandy..

Comment: Reminds me of people who blame the compiler is broken when there code doesn't work, its 99.999999% likely not to be the compiler but maybe just maybe it is.. didn't cross my mind til today to consider that the debugger was broke - i guess i was thinking too statistically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody experiencing weird behaviour when running `gdb` under emacs/linux

If you recently upgraded to emacs 24 understand that `gdb` is broken and that you need to now use `gud-gdb`

for more details follow:

[Emacs gdb not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435183/emacs-gdb-not-running)

[gud-gdb emacs 24 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676135/gud-gdb-emacs-24-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on mac.
I installed gdb-apple, and was then able to set breakpoints / inspect variables in a shared library that was loaded inside of python.