# Getting gdb to work with emacs 24

Tags: c, emacs, gdb, emacs24

Realised after much head-scratching in relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633968/cannot-access-memory-at-address-function-parameter-passing-isssue) that `gdb` seems to be broken in `emacs 24`

So I have switched to `gud-gdb`

But I now notice that the very handy red dots on break points don't seem to work in `gud-gdb`

Does anyone have a definitive answer on how to be able to sensibly debug C code using `emacs 24`?

I never had any problems in `emacs 23` but `24` has caused me all sorts of bother..

Maybe I should switch back to `emacs 23` but this seems a little regressive?

Is the new method to use `gdb-mi` in some way?

Would be very interested to learn what best-practice is with respect to `emacs 24` - haven't been able to find any relevant (`emacs 24` specific) tutorials on the interwebs

Comment: please ignore drive-by downvote from a disgruntled cut-and-paster..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb is working for me out of box on GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

If it still doesn't work for you, please try to use command:

```
gdb --fullname binary_name
```

insead of default

```
gdb -i=mi binary_name
```

Comment: i think that might be what running M-x gud-gdb is doing

Comment: Can you try download latest version of gdb-mi.el from https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el
an try to load it?

Comment: `--fullname did not work for me. I get:(gdb) Undefined command: "1-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "2-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "3-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "4-gdb-set".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "5-enable-pretty-printing".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "6-file-list-exec-source-files".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "7-file-list-exec-source-file".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "8-gdb-show".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "9-stack-info-frame".  Try "help"`