# Advice on getting gdb-mi.el to work in GNU Emacs 24.3.1

Tags: emacs, gdb

## Question

I am an Emacs novice and would like to try the newer MI interface for gdb integration as provided by [gdb-mi.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GDB-MI). Based on what I've read, this is now the default that gets used when executing M-x gdb, so I'd hoped that everything would work out of the box.

I'm working on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Using the default gdb-mi.el, I don't seem to get messages related to segfaults (or other reasons for the debugged program stopping) printed to the GUD interface. Using the latest gdb-mi.el, I get the messages, but no command prompt to indicate when commands have finished executing.

So my question is whether there is revision of gdb-mi.el (and related files) that an emacs novice can use to get things running reliably. Similar questions have been asked before, e.g. [gud-gdb emacs 24 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676135/gud-gdb-emacs-24-not-working) and
[Getting gdb to work with emacs 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662444/getting-gdb-to-work-with-emacs-24). It looks like the advice there is to revert back to older GDB interfaces (gdb-ui.el), but I'd really like to get the MI based interface working.

The rest of the question text contains some background information on what I've tried thus far in the hopes that it may help other novices stumbling around in the dark.

I have virtually no experience using Emacs lisp, so I'm probably biting off more than I can chew, but would be more than happy to hack around a bit if anyone is willing to offer advice on where to start.

## Things I've tried thus far

In order to get things working, I've been using a simple little program to induce a segmentation fault so I have something to debug.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void doCrash()
{
    memset(0x0,1,1);
}

int main (int argc, const char ** argv)
{
    printf("hello\n");
    doCrash();
    printf("bye\n");
}
```

I compiled this using 'g++ -g main.cpp', so I've got debug info for gdb to use.

I then launch gdb via emacs using 'M-x gdb' (and run it like this: 'gdb -i=mi a.out'), and then do 'M-x gdb-many-windows' to get a nice multi-window layout.

### Issue #1: No notification of hitting segfaults, breakpoints, etc.

Using the default gdb-mi.el file, when I run the program, there is no message to indicate a segfault occurred.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
(gdb) c
Continuing.
(gdb)
```

There is a hint as to what happened in the 'Threads' buffer window, but that's won't be useful when debugging larger programs in anger:

```
1 process 31800 stopped in main (argc=1,argv=0x7fffffffe3c8) of main.cpp:11
```

### Issue #2: No command prompt

Upgrading gdb-mi.el to the [latest version from github](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el) (which I knew in advance was unlikely to work perfectly as it probably relies on other lisp modules), the prompt goes missing very soon after running gdb, but I do get messages on segfaults and the like:

```
(gdb) r          <--- I still have a prompt here
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff732efd9 in memset () from /lib/libc.so.6
bt               <--- No prompt anymore, but gdb commands work
bt
#0  0x00007ffff732efd9 in memset () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040066c in doCrash () at main.cpp:6
#2  0x000000000040068c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe3c8) at main.cpp:12
```

The lack of prompt may not seem like a big thing, but it's obviously less than ideal having no indication of when gdb & emacs has finished processing something and is ready for new input.

Comment: Have you tried that after starting emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Tobias - Thanks for the advice. I retried with the latest gdb-mi.el using emacs -Q, but the result is the same. I did notice something new in the *Messages* buffer after doing 'M-x gdb': "let: Symbol's function definition is void: add-function". So that may be an indication of things not being quite as they should be.

Does gdb work fine for you in emacs? If so, what versions of gdb and emacs are you using?